# Radian unit mystery (damped oscillator)

Tags: dimensional-analysis, rotation, angular-velocity, si-units

I would be extremely grateful for any help that anyone could offer here.

I am interested in solving the optical bloch equations for the excited state population Rabi oscillations with damping due to spontaneous decay. The problem that I have is not solving the equations mathematically, but making sense of the units.

Essentially I am solving a system of differential equations which are stated as

$$\frac{d\rho_{ee}}{dt} = i\Omega (\rho_{eg} - \rho_{ge}) - \Gamma \rho_{ee}$$
where $\rho_{ee}$ is the probability of being in the excited state.

$\Omega$ is defined to be the rabi frequency - which is an angular frequency such that the period T satisfies $\Omega T = 2\pi$ i.e. $ \Omega$ must have units of $\rm rad\ s^{-1}$. $\Gamma$ clearly has  the same units. $\rho_{ee}$ is the population of the excited state.

The solution ends up with terms like
$$e^{-(3\Gamma/4)t}\cos \Omega_R t$$
where $\Omega_R$ is of the same units as $\Omega$ and $\Gamma$. I am having severe difficulty understanding the units here - surely the exponent of the exponential (although dimensionless) has units of rad?

If one sets $\Omega = 0$ then one recovers $e^{-\Gamma t}$ which again has an exponent with units of rad.  One would expect the excited state population to decay as $e^{-t/\tau}$ where $\tau$ is the lifetime of the state in s. I am used to this being a unitless ratio.

Does it make sense to have an exponential with a unit of radians? and how does this relate to the natural lifetime of the excited state?

Moreover the differential equation seems to suggest $\rho_{ee}$ has units of radians which is also puzzling... Are $\Gamma$ and $\rho$ actually inverse times in the differential equation and if so how do they get converted to rad s$^{-1}$ when they become the argument of the cosines.

I am confused because there is a physical difference of 2$\pi$ between frequency and angular frequency, so it matters which one $\Gamma$ is.
Any light that anyone could shed would be amazing!
Thanks

Comment: Relevant: ["Question about Radian as a unit"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/422617/145491), ["Why does radians disappear in equation ="](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/592965/145491), ["Are units of angle really dimensionless?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/252288/145491)

Comment: Is $\rho$ a population or a probability, you've written that it is both.

Answer (score 6):

> Does it make sense to have an exponential with a unit of radians?

Yes. This is the famous Euler identity:

\begin{align}
e^{ix} &= 1 + ix + \frac{(ix)^2}{2!} + \frac{(ix)^3}{3!} + \cdots
\\ &= \left( 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \cdots
\right) + i \cdot\left(
x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \cdots
\right)
\\ &= \cos x + i\sin x
\end{align}

In the context of your specific question, I would prefer to say that it makes sense for the argument of the cosine to be a dimensionless number, rather than any dimensionful angle.  In fact, the arguments of cosine and sine *should* be dimensionless, if you want to be able to use their Taylor series definitions, as above.

> Surely the exponent of the exponential (although dimensionless) has units of rad? … I am used to this being a unitless ratio.

The radian is a dimensionless ratio: the ratio of an arc length  to the corresponding radius.

Compare with resistor-capacitor circuits, where the capacitor has a frequency-dependent complex impedance $Z_C = (j\omega C)^{-1}$. The frequency response of the oscillating circuit has a feature at angular frequency $\omega  = 1/RC$. In the DC limit, the voltage across the capacitor decays away with lifetime $\tau = 1/\Gamma = RC$. The basic relationship between the $e$-folding time and the angular frequency is the same as in your problem.

You can think about this from the basic structure of the differential equations.  If you have

$$
\frac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm dt^2} \phi = -\omega^2 \phi,
$$
then $\omega$ is an angular frequency. But with
$$
\frac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm dt^2} \phi = +\Gamma^2 \phi,
$$
the solution is exponential growth or decay with lifetime $\tau=1/\Gamma$.
What you have here, with the basic shape
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\phi
=
(i\omega + \Gamma)\phi
$$
is, in a handwaving way, an oscillatory bit and an exponential bit.
The factor of $2\pi$ comes from the way that exponentials are related to circles.

Answer (score 4):

*Does it make sense to have an exponential with a unit of radians?*

Yes, because although the angle has a "label" - radians - to alert the reader as to how the angle was defined, it does not have a dimension because the radian is defined via the ratio of two quantities which have the same dimensions, eg angle subtended at the centre of a circle in radians = $\dfrac {\text {arc length in metres}}{\text{circumference of circle in metres}}$.